# Loop through jQuery array in each function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have data that I get from an API in another function. To get the data I do this:

```
var posts = get_posts();
```

I can then print to the console:

```
console.info( posts );
```

I'll end up with something like this:

```
[]
  0: {id: 123, date: "2018-01-01T12:00:00", slug: "asdf-xyz", author: 1, media: 1, …}
  1: {id: 123, date: "2018-01-01T12:00:00", slug: "asdf-xyz", author: 1, media: 1, …}
  ...
```

There's multiple entries in this array with various bits of data.

However, if I then try to loop through them and do something, the each statement doesn't do anything. It's as if it's completely ignored (which it probably is).

```
$.each( posts, function( index, record ) {

    alert( index );

});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

***Edit***

This is the code I have inside a function which returns (or should) return the array. Using a simple `console.log` returns the data, however using `stringify` just returns `[]`.

```
$.each( object, function( key, value ) {

    var post = {
        id: value.id,
        ...
    };

    posts.push( post );

});

console.log( posts ); // prints the data out
```

JavaScript is not my strongest coding language so I'm assuming I'm setting up the data incorrectly perhaps?

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: How are you getting the array `posts`? Through A(synchronous)JAX?

Comment: When sharing data on Stack Overflow, it is often better to show the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(posts))` so that we're not trying to guess as to the actual structure/data. It also helps because as you can see, your initial log shows an empty array, but expanding it shows entries; this is because expanding the data makes it so the data is retrieved at the moment of expansion, not at the moment of logging.

Comment: Using the JSON `stringify` function, I get `[]` in the console. I'll update the question with some extra bits that might be useful. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It should be alright. I've put together a working example for you. Can you spot the difference between your code and the working snippet below?

```js
var posts = [
  { name: 'Post1' },
  { name: 'Post2' }
];

$.each(posts, function(index, record) {
  console.log(index, record);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The issue might be in the code that you're using to populate the array. Can you provide a bit more context?

Comment: I've updated the question. Perhaps it's how I'm formatting the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can print all the object with:

```
$.each( posts, function( index, record ) { alert(  JSON.stringify(record) ) });
```

Or specific keys using

```
$.each( posts, function( index, record ) { alert(  record["slug"] ) });
```

Run the code and see the demo

```js
$(function(){
    var posts = [];

    posts.push({id: 123, date: "2018-01-01T12:00:00", slug: "asdf-xyz", author: 1, media: 1});
    
    posts.push({id: 123, date: "2018-01-01T12:00:00", slug: "asdf-xyz", author: 1, media: 1});

    $.each( posts, function( index, record ) { alert(  JSON.stringify(record) ) });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Whilst this does seem to work, when put into my code, it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: I just edited, now you can paste it into your project
You have to run it into an `on ready` or another event.
For example:
`$(function(){   /* PUT WHOLE THE CODE HERE */    });`